# any compact way to make promise as sequence?

Tags: javascript, promise

Here, I want the promise to be resolved one by one.  `Q.when` seems a good wrapper for values.  If I already have an array of Promises, beside using `.then(function(){return next();})`, Is there a compact way to do so?

[Here is my JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/fataco/edit?html,js,console,output) And the relevant JavaScript:

```
function wrap(v) {
  var defer = Q.defer();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('okay, fine!');
    defer.resolve(v);
  }, 3000);
  return defer.promise;
}
/*
wrap(1)
  .then(function() {
    return wrap(3);
  })
  .then(function(v) {
    console.log(v);
  });
*/

/* map result is an array of promise
when using reduce, it will resolve one by one. 
*/

[1, 3, 4, 5].map(wrap)
  .reduce(Q.when, Q(undefined))
  .then(function(v) {
    console.log(done);
  });
```

Comment: If you've already got an array of promises there is *nothing* you can do except wait (`Q.all`).

Comment: Do you need to support a sequence of dynamic size or you have a predefined array?

Comment: Code relevant to your question MUST be pasted into the question and not only available in an external link.  This is a Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: @Bergi, the intention here is to make a sequence.  In this case,  the console.log will be logged out every 3 seconds.

Comment: @Peng: I just said that you cannot make it a sequence *in hindsight* when you've already done `.map(wrap)`, which started all the timeouts concurrently.

Comment: @Bergi.  Yes, I also found my silliness.   moving wrap into reduce function works as I attached below. But underneath, the wrap function called 8 times  which is weird. Still looking into that.

Comment: See if [spex.sequence](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/docs/code/sequence.md) can help you with what you want to achieve, provided your sequence is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in Q's github repo.  it seems in the `reduce` function we could still use `.then`.

`Q.when` is not supposed to use with promise.

```js
function wrap(v) {
  var defer = Q.defer();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += ('okay, fine! here is ' + v + '<br/>');
    defer.resolve(v);
  }, 3000);
  return defer.promise;
}

[1, 3, 4, 5]
.reduce(function(soFar, f) {
  return soFar
    .then(function(v) {
      return wrap(f);
    });
}, Q(undefined));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.0.1/q.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't want to `wrap(soFar)`, you just want to `return soFar.then(…)`

Comment: Yes. You are awesome.  Thank you!
http://jsbin.com/fataco/8/edit?html,js,console,output